# VBA loop works using F8 but not when running free

Tags: loops

I realise these errors are unique to the code written so no previous examples have helped much, except I can report that I do trap any errors, and none show up.  The procedure is long but here is the part that is being missed out in realtime.

```
    ...With rsFacilityStock
        .Edit
        !TotalShares = !TotalShares + rsPending!Shares
        
        Select Case rsPending!BuySell
        Case BUY_STOCK
            strTradeType = "BUY"
            lngMovementID = MOVEMENT_PURCHASE
        Case PARTSELL_STOCK, SELL_STOCK
            If rsPending!BuySell = PARTSELL_STOCK Then
                strTradeType = "PSALE"
            Else
                strTradeType = "SALE"
                **!Archived = True
                !ArchiveDate = rsPending!PurchaseDate**
            End If
            
            'Build Array for clearing out sharesleft
            intSaleCount = intSaleCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve SaleRecord(1 To intSaleCount)
            With SaleRecord(intSaleCount)
                .FacilityStockID = rsPending!FacilityStockID
                .TradeDate = rsPending!PurchaseDate
                .SharesTraded = rsPending!Shares
            End With
            
        Case 4
            strTradeType = "ROLLO"
            booCashPot = False
        End Select
        
        .Update
    End With...
```

The part between the ** is what fails when the trade is a Sale. I note that the strTradeType does get set but the Archiving fails.  My suspicion is that it is the .Update that is failing.  Just don't know why.  Ideas welcome.

Comment: After further work I now think this part is not run. The issue is further up the code with an "Item not found in collection" error. This may be an .EOF issue.  Please ignore this question for now.

Comment: This fixed it!  It needed to have the history of compiled code removed. Access is great at storing stuff you can't access and then it corrupts the running of the accde file.  See here for something we should all do before going live.  http://fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Errors/Bad_DLL_Calling_Convention.asp  These guys also produce a good app that analyses your code too.  I can't work without it.